# Lock a vector with a mutex - Boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, boost, vector

I'm writing code for a router and I want to, after receiving a packet on my receiver thread, to store that packet (which is of type "unsigned char *" as of now) in a vector. I have two receiver threads that are linked to two different interfaces, and a receiver thread should only store the packet received if another thread isn't accessing the vector already.

Other than the two receiving threads I will have a main thread processing the packets and two sending threads, one for each interface. Total thread count is 5. To prevent trouble when the different threads are writing or reading from the vector I've come to hear of a mutex, which supposedly should lock the vector for other (in this case) threads until after the thread in question is done reading or writing from the vector.

What I want to know is how this is processed into code. Some examples would be very much appreciated. I'm all pretty new to C++, Boost and Raw Sockets. And to top it off I'm not very fond of using different classes yet in C++. I know very well how they work in Java and C#, but what I've come to find is that C++ is very different (because of the header files). I have all my code in one giant main class, which might not be very good coding style, but that's how it works for now.

Should I create a class (.h and .cpp file) for handling this vector or should I just implement it in my giant main class and if so I would be very happy for some simple examples. Below is an example of how I want my program to work. I already have the RecvThread in place and I am able to print out the MAC Hdr of a packet.

```
void RecvThread()
{
    //receive a packet


    while(true)
    {
        //get lock status from vector

        if(vector is locked)
        {
            usleep(10000);
        }
        else
        {
            //lock vector
            //save packet in vector
            //unlock vector
        }
    }
}

void SendThread()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //get lock status from vector

        if(vector is locked)
        {
            usleep(10000);
        }
        else
        {
            //lock vector
            //get packet from vector
            //unlock vector
        }
    }

    //send the packet
}

void MainThread()
{

    while(true)
    {
        if(recv vector is empty)
        {
            usleep(10000);
        }
        else if(recv vector is locked)
        {
            usleep(10000);
        }
        else
        {
            //lock recv vector
            //get packet in front of queue
            //unlock recv vector
            //process packet (update different fields)
            //get packet interface (either 1 or 2)
            if(send vector (matching interface) is locked)
            {
                usleep(10000);
            }
            else
            {
                //lock send vector (matching interface)
                //save packet to send vector (matching interface)
                //unlock send vector (matching interface)
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //create Recv vector
    //create Send vector 1 and 2 (one for each interface)
    //create and join RecvThread 1 and 2
    //create and join SendThread 1 and 2
    //create and join MainThread
}
```

Comment: You can use .h files and .cpp without having a class. You have a class if you write the word class in one of them.

Comment: In your case you would lock a mutex where you wrote the //lock vector comments. You don't need to get the lock status though, the boost library will handle that for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this gives you the idea. Didn't test it as it's obviously incomplete :)
The key is `boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mx_);` as this line can only be executed by one thread at a time. What's actually happening is that thread A for instance calls this function and since it is the first thread to arrive there `boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mx_);` returns immediately and the thread can proceed into what is called the critical section (code segment after the lock). Basically `boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mx_);` only returns if no other thread is inside the critical section. In case that the critical section is already being accessed by another thread, `boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mx_);` simply doesn't return until the other thread left the critical section. In order for the waiting thread to proceed now, the mutex needs to be unlocked. In boost, this is automatically done once the blocking thread (the first to enter the section) leaves the scope of the function with the critical section. Leaving the scope destroys the variable  `mx_` which allows another mutex with the same name to be created and locked.

EDIT: You don't specifically lock one variable such as a vector. You lock a segment of your code, where that variable is accessed.

```
class Receiver{
private:
  boost::mutex mx_;
  int *data_;   // I need protection

public:
  bool receive_data(){
    // Prepare connection and do some stuff...

    void some_function(){
      // Before we access data_, we need to make sure only the current thread does so.
      // Mutex will unlock once the scope of this function is left
      boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mx_); 

      // Access data_ here (mutex is locked)
      //....
    } // End of scope and mutex unlocks automatically since it's destroyed
    return true;  // Will unlock the mutex since the function's scope is left. 
  }
};
```

Comment: It definitively give me an idea of how it should work, but is this only doable in a class? Right now my RecvThread function just receives a packet from a raw interface instead of running a class...
My main concern is how I should code the specific part of creating the vector that is lockable..

Comment: No no sorry, of course you can lock it anywhere. Just do it inside a function so it automatically unlocks once the function returns.

Comment: So I could write a function: void LockVector(vector<unsigned char *>) and in there run the "boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mx_);" and once the method returns in the end the lock would be released?

Comment: @Zeliax: Pass the vector by non-`const` reference. The important part is to establish the `lock_guard` *before* attempting to `push_back` characters. Trying to add stuff to the vector, and all implications such modifications bear, are the critical problems here. Also, please don't say "lock the vector". As potAito already stated, you don't lock isolated objects but generally prevent a control flow from passing synchronization point, e.g. a `mutex`.

Comment: @Zeliax Short answer: no you can't create a lock function (not this way at least, you would have to use a mutex which needs to be unlcoked manually)

Comment: @Zeliax Long answer: Your LockVector function would need to include all the critical code, meaning the code that accesses the vector, like push_back(), size() etc. Therefore it makes more sense to write a method such as addToVector(int data){ // Use mutex in here } because this way you compress your critical section into one method. Btw. critical section is what the part of the code is called which accesses shared resources, meaning resources which can be accessed by multiple threads. So you want only one or no thread to be inside a critical section at any given time!

Comment: @potAito That long answer was the "pot" of gold at the end of the rainbow! :D Thanks a lot! Would it make sense to have an AddToVector and RemoveFromVector function? Would these two collide since they both would be able to call the guard function? And a last small question: Would it be a good idea to instantiate the mx_ and vector variable as global variables? That is in the top of the main.cpp file before any functions..

Comment: @Zeliax Glad to hear that :) Yes it would make sense to implement both functions. Just remember that as soon as a function can change the vector, you also need to guard all read accesses. Meaning you would need another function for reading the i-th element such as getFromVector(int i){} (you don't want to read a variable while it's being rewritten -> errors). Now to your last question. Yes that makes totally sense and that's why I encapsulated it in a class. Whenever you call boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mx_); the variable "mx_" needs to be known in this scope. So global works always